# In python how can I set multiple values of a list to zero simultaneously?

Tags: python

Conceptually, I want to do:

```
arr[20:] = 0
```

where `arr` is a `list`. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Yup. It's a list, sorry.

Comment: Would be nice if whatever solution you use gracefully handles the case where the original size of your list is shorter than 20 items.

Comment: Well the graceful behavior I would expect would be to leave a list of 20 or fewer items untouched. The `xrange` for-loop does that, I think, since there are no `i` values to iterate over. But it doesn't matter for my application since I'm hacking it together and I know i always have 10,000 data points

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do it directly using slice assignment.

```
arr[20:] = [0] * (len(arr) - 20)
```

But the natural way is just to iterate.

```
for i in xrange(20, len(arr)):
    arr[i] = 0
```

Comment: What about `arr[20:] = [0 for i in range(20,len(arr))]`?  Shouldn't that be in this answer, also?

Comment: Since the OP knows that arr is always 10,000 items long, and assuming this is an operation that will need to be done fairly often, then there may be some advantage in precalculating `trailing_zeros = [0]*(10000-20)`, and then simply doing `arr[20:] = trailing_zeros` when needed.

Comment: If "0" is a filler for a mutable type, you have to iterate.

Answer (score 9):

Here are a couple of options:

List comprehension

```
>>> a = [1]*50
>>> a = [aa if i < 20 else 0 for i,aa in enumerate(a)]
>>> a
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

List slice assignment:

```
>>> a = [1]*50
>>> a[20:] = [0 for aa in a[20:]]
>>> a
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Zip(*zip):

```
>>> a = [1]*50
>>> a[20:] = zip(*zip(a[20:],itertools.repeat(0)))[1]
```

Comment: I nominate the zip example for inclusion in the Python Obfuscated Code FAQ.  Gnarly!

Answer (score 4):

```
arr.fill(0)
```

[numpy.ndarray.fill()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html) will fill ndarray with scalar value

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that you will pass the array to that will zero out the array.  I haven't used Python in a while, so I won't attempt to show you the Python code.  In that function you could use a `for` or `while` loop to iterate through each value and setting each one equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you use list comprehension you make a copy of the list, so there is memory waste.
Use list comprehension or slicing to make new lists, use for cicles to set your list items correctly.