# Array index manipulation with multiple conditions

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I want to change every index in an array that lies between two values.
I know:

```
a[a>10]=0
```

will change every index to 0 if the condition that the index itself is greater than 10 is true.
What I now want to achieve is to set every array index to 0 if two conditions are true, if for example the index is greater than 10 and less than 50, but

`a[a>10 and a<50]=0`

won't work.
I know I can to do this with a few lines of code but I feel like this wouldn't be the most elegant solution therefore my question is something like this possible in a similar elegant way as my simple example above, maybe also a one-liner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In python how can I set multiple values of a list to zero simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390517/in-python-how-can-i-set-multiple-values-of-a-list-to-zero-simultaneously)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parenthesis around each condition:

```
a[(i > 10) & (i < 50)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
a=np.arange(1,10)
a[(a>3) & (a<7)] = 0
# output: [1 2 3 0 0 0 7 8 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this (click for a demo):

[`if i>10 and i<50: l[:] = [0]*len(l)`](https://tio.run/#python38pr)

Let's break this down:

`l[:] = value` is a slicing statement. This is equivalent to `l.__setitem__(slice(), value)`. For the built-in list object, leaving out the index to the left of the colon implies an index of zero, and leaving out the index to the right of the colon implies an index of the length of the array minus one. In other words, by leaving out both numbers on the sides of `:`, we implicitly set the entire list.

`[0]*len(l)` takes a list with a single element, 0, and multiplies it by the length of the list, creating a list of `[0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0]` as long as the original list.

---

If you want to do this in a single expression, you can write:

```
           an empty parameter list (slice() uses None,None without arguments 
           |         (which is equivalent to `l[:]`)
           |
           |  ternary operator
           v  vv
l[slice(**([] if (i > 10 and i < 50) else 0,0))] = [0]*len(l)`
  ^     ^^
  |      kwargs argument unpacking
  |
  create a slice object -- l[x:y] is just syntactic sugar for l[slice(x, y)
```

This is syntactic sugar for setting `[0]*len(l)` to `l[:]` if the condition within holds true and `[0]*len(l)` to `l[0:0]` when the condition is false. `l[0:0]` is an empty range, so nothing changes.