# Replacing values in a list by looping without making the size of the list smaller/larger

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have a list li. When I loop over it and replace zeros with new values the size of the list changes.  I want to keep the same size but be able to manipulate the list.

```
str0 = "Hi"
str1 = "Bye"
li = [[[0, 0] for y in range(len(str1)+1)] for x in range(len(str0)+1)] #correct size
print(li) 
#output: [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
print(li[0][0][0])
#output: 0

for i in range(0, len(str0) + 1):
    li[i][0] = i
print(li)
#output of incorrect size:[[0, [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [1, [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [2, [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
print(li[0][0][0])
#output: Typeerror
```

Note output should be: where column = 0, row = i according to the loop

Answer (score 0):

If I get your explanation correct you would like to have

```
print(li)
[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[2, 2], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

For that you can do one of the following:

```
# a)
for i in range(0, len(str0) + 1):
    li[i][0] = [i, i]
```

a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390517/in-python-how-can-i-set-multiple-values-of-a-list-to-zero-simultaneously):

```
# b)
for i in range(0, len(str0) + 1):
    li[i][0] = [i]*2
```

or like this

```
# c)
import numpy as np
# rest of your code
li = np.array(li)
for i in range(0, len(str0) + 1):
    li[i][0][:] = i
li = list(li)
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: The output should keep the value of the column = 0 and then the row here should be i. I am going to edit the question making it clearer.

Comment: I am afraid I still don't get it. What is column and row if we have 3 nested lists? Could you give the correct output for your example please?